# Организация приватных функций в Go

Tags: golang

Вопрос касается стиля программирования на Go. В других объектно-ориентированных языках есть приватные статические функции, которые используются только в пределах одного класса. Вопрос касается того, как идеологически более правильно организовать что-то подобное в Go.

Например, пусть есть код:

```
package mypackage

type MyStruct struct {
    ...
}

func (foo *MyStruct) PublicFunc() string {
    // Здесь используются поля из MyStruct
    ...
    return foo.privateFunc()
}

func (foo *MyStruct) privateFunc() string {
    // Здесь НЕ используются поля MyStruct
    ...
    return ...
}
```

Вопрос в том, стоит ли privateFunc привязывать к MyStruct? В других языках такую функцию можно было бы объявить как static.

С одной стороны, такая привязка показывает, что эта функция используется только в пределах работы с MyStruct. Но я сомневаюсь, что так стоит делать в Go, поскольку в этом языке все функции находятся вне структур. Есть мысль такие функции не привязывать к структуре, а просто располагать их в том же файле, где объявлена MyStruct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется, если privateFunc функция не использует поля MyStruct, не нужно ее делать методом этой структуры, так вы только людей запутаете. Имя функции начинается с маленькой буквы, поэтому за пределами пакета mypackage ее все равно видно не будет, а большего как правило и не надо.

В общем, такое впечатление, что вы пытаетесь принести свои привычки из других ЯП в мир Go, но полного аналога им нету, языки разные, их идеология и применяемые подходы, посему, тоже. В данном случае, просто обзывайте функцию именем с маленькой буквы, располагайте ее в том же файле, что и MyStruct. Если вам этого мало, можете еще комментарий написать, где разъясните, какое и где предполагается использование функции. Других средств в Go нет, и, в данном случае, я лично не вижу их необходимости. Это чистой воды "вкусовщина".